# kivy clock: clock not executing callback

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to schedule my service app to send a message to my main app. Both codes are able to send and receive messages. In this code however, when I try and use Clock.schedule_interval to execute a function, it fails to execute. I realize that the callback is weak-referenced, and I made a reference to the original callback, like the kivy reference site suggests.

I know for sure that osc.sendMsg works, because when I defined a function that uses osc.sendMsg, it successfully sent the message to my other main.py when I called that function. However, when I put self.answer_message in Clock.schedule_interval, something goes wrong and it does not send the message. I want this code to send the message every second.

I used pdb and found that when I put answer.answer_message() under message_callback, it calls osc.py and sends the message to my other code. When I put answer.time() under message_callback however, it creates a clock event, but it does not call answer_message. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my service/main.py:

```
import time
from kivy.lib import osc
from kivy.clock import Clock


serviceport = 3000
activityport = 3001


def message_callback(message, *args):
    print("got a message! %s" % message)
    #global switch
    #switch = message[2]
    answer = function()
    answer.time()


class function(object):
    def answer_message(self,dt):
            osc.sendMsg('~/kivyinstall/sahil/reply/step3_active', [time.asctime(time.localtime()), ], port=activityport)
    def time(self):
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.answer_message, 1)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    osc.init()
    oscid = osc.listen(ipAddr='127.0.0.1', port=serviceport)
    osc.bind(oscid, message_callback, '~/kivyinstall/sahil/reply/step3_active/service')

    while True:
            osc.readQueue(oscid)
```